# Can Bronzor be a good special attacker for the third gym in Pokemon Diamond?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

So far my team is made up of the following Pokemon:

Grotle

Golbat

I am wondering if I add Bronzor, would it help with my special attack? If so, would it work with my current team? (I'm headed to the town of the third gym.)

Comment: What you choose for you team is very much up to personal opinion.  Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: There's a question that could have easily been answered which is the title, which you are straying from. That edit didn't make any form of sense, do you actually read the main question? I'm playing Pokemon diamond if you do not wish to help move on to the next question.

Comment: @Ashley Nunn The question was extremely simple and he tried to make points that made 0% sense, "Suggesting an option for a team, out of, oh, I dunno 718 is far too broad to be useful" I clearly stated this is diamond version

Comment: @LumaForSmash While you did so in your title, yes, the body isn't clear (neither is the tag). Also, the body of your question doesn't completely match the title (and the question in the title is a little broad. A good special attacker compared to what? For what purpose? Do you want them to be useful for the third gym?). The more you can tell us, and the more specific you can be, without getting hostile, the better off you will be.

Comment: Also, asking people what they suggest makes this open to opinion. Either you have a specific question about Bronzor, or you are asking for a team recommendation. Perhaps you might want to consider narrowing down what you really want to know.

Comment: There is no tag for diamond so that is already irrelevant, and I asked if bronzor CAN BE a good special attacker therefore asking for comparison wouldn't make much sense the question is very simple and all I needed was a simple answer not criticism

Comment: @LumaForSmash There is a tag that applies - I just added it (we tend to go with tags for each gen, as it were). You asked for a team recommendation when you asked what else to use if he wasn't able to do what you want. I'm not criticizing, I am just trying to focus your question so that it works well with the site, so you get the best answer possible.

Comment: I don't really play Pokemon games, so maybe I'm misunderstanding, but it sounds like they're asking for the pros and cons of a specific pokemon as a third member of a team, not for random opinions on who is a good idea. The number of other options would then be irrelevant. This seems fairly focused.

Comment: @DCShannon It is NOW more focused.  Pre-edit, it most certainly was not.  It removes the opinionated section, but still should be focused more on what, exactly, is attempted to be accomplished.

Comment: @Frank Ah, yep. Didn't see the edit. Might've needed closed before. Looks fine now.

Comment: Is it better?  Yup.  Is it clear?  Sorta.  There's still nothing here that explains the reasoning.  It's definitely not *needed*, but it would certainly escalate this into a much better question.  @LumaForSmash I'm certainly not focusing on you, specifically.  I just see problematic questions, I will weigh in.  It's one of my privileges; spend enough time on the site, and you, too, can do so.  It's just an attempt at guiding you towards our standards.  If you take it as pure criticism, well, it's not.  We have standards.  Standards that must be met.

Comment: @ Ashley Nunn Why would you change my question to "Can Bronzor be a good special attacker for the third gym" that was not at all what I wanted. I wanted to know if it was good overall. That was fairly obvious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short; not really*

[Bronzor](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bronzor_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29)'s base stats for it's special attack is 24. That's in the bottom 20 of all pokemon (It's attack is similarly low, however). [Most builds](http://www.smogon.com/dex/dp/pokemon/bronzor/) tend to focus on bolstering the defenses so that it can take more hits. Also teaching it Reflect and Light Screen to make it (and any Pokemon you might switch in) even more durable.

Once it evolves into [Bonzong](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bronzong_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) at lvl33 it becomes considerably more competent as an attacker, But the base stats for Attack are higher than Special attack by 10, and most [builds for Bronzong](http://www.smogon.com/dex/dp/pokemon/bronzong/) reflect this.

Also, you may want to keep in mind typing. You are headed into the third gym, which means ghost type Pokemon. Bronzor/Bronzong are Steel/Psychic, it will take regular (1x) damage from Ghost type attacks (Psychic is weak to ghost, Steel is strong against ghost before gen6. The average out to neutral). Also the Bronzor will come with one of two abilities, Levitate or Heatproof. Levitate will make it immune to one of it's weaknesses (ground), while Heatproof will reduce another weakness (fire) to regular effectiveness. Levitate is generally considered better.

---

*But; **the above ultimately doesn't matter too much.**

All those builds, and consideration for movesets? That is largely for competitive *player* vs *player* battles. Sure, you can take those builds and strategies and apply them to the NPC battles along the journey, it may even help you win more efficiently. But the story allows you to abuse healing items, and to out-level your opponents.

If you want a Sp.Attack Bronzor/Bronzong - Go for it! [EV train it](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Effort_values) for Sp.Attack and get it the best Special moves you can (through leveling up and TMs), have a few good status moves, like Toxic, or the previously mentioned reflect/lightscreen.

Typing is still important, however, so do be aware that your new Bronzor might not be as strong against the various ghosts of the 3rd gym as you might expect, as it's Psychic typing cancels out the resistance it would get from it's Steel type. On the flip side, the Steel typing means you are immune to any of the poison attacks they might use, and if you have any Psychic attacks, they will do 2x damage against many of the Ghosts as half of them are Ghastly/Haunter/Gengar, which are also Poison typed.

Comment: in gen 4, steel/psychic takes x1 from ghost attacks -- the steel nerf was at the start of gen 6

Comment: @Pyritie Derp, I knew the type charts were different, but while confirming I missed ghost's 1/2 damage to steel (or maybe I was looking at the wrong chart). Thanks, I'll update this.